Dark spots on tomato plant leaves
I have three indeterminate baby-tomato plants that all have gotten leaves with these dark spots. It almost looks like ink spots, but also affects the edge of the leaf somewhat. It has mostly affected lower older and larger leaves, but I notice some smaller new leaves also have some blue/dark edges. The tomatoes are planted in pots, and get liquid fertilizer in recommended dosage. They seem healthy in general with plenty of unripe tomatoes. There are some winged aphids present on the plants, but not very many IMO and I doubt this to be the cause. The underside of the leaves seem to be fine. Is it possible to tell the cause from the picture below? Google was not very helpfull. This example is a mildly affected leaf.
The recent weather has been cold (10C at night, 20C daytime) wet and rainy, and the issue did accelerate the last week or so. Could it be some type of mold due to the moisture?
If anyone have a strong suspicion of cause and suggested action I would be gratefull.


My guess is fungus. Try a pH-changing solution and spray on the leaves. CuSO4+Ca(OH)2 maybe better

@Reihani I also have fungus/mold that as my number 1 suspect. I just removed the worst leaves, but removing everything with any hint of this seems  to be worse than the disease. I'll avoid chemicals for now, and see how it goes. Thanks for your suggestion/opinion.
